# crash issue in .net application - windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, crash

I needed some help to debug a crash in windows .net application.

We have a .net plugin running (written in c#) and it has crashed once during automation testing , we dont have a coredump or any logs , only an event log which was generated which gives fault offset.

In c++, we generate a .map file to which we can map this fault offset to get a rough idea about the location of the crash but I am not able to generate such .map file for a c# project.

Can anyone help in generating the map file or about the approach to follow to resolve this issue?

[image]

I have tried creating a map file by providing linker options to msbuild while compiling above project but it failed to create a map file.